# How to connect a washing machine to a bathroom sink via a quick coupling connector

Tags: washer, adapter

Planning to install stackable washer dryer in bathroom.  If I use a bathroom sink quick-coupling adapter for the water supply, which hose, hot or cold, do I connect and what should I do with the other connection?

Comment: Most washers/dishwashers put the quick coupler on the faucet, not on the hoses/pipes.  You then turn on the hot and/or cold taps as you like.

Comment: take a picture for what is under the sink

Comment: If the washer has two hoses then you use both hoses.  I only trust quick couplers for temporary use(when using the washer), so would like proper connections, shutoff valves, tees on the hose/pipes.

Comment: Make sure your bathroom sink can handle the peak flow of water pumped out of the washer -- many bathroom sinks and drainpipes are too small for that.

Comment: @Armand I think OP is only hooking up the water supply, but yes, don't drain into the sink plumbing. The plumbing can't handle the typical flow from a washing machine and water will back-flow out of the sink.

Comment: Huh?  Should you use *both* hoses—hot *and* cold?  Do you wash your clothes only with cold water?

Comment: Many of us do wash only with cold.

Answer (score 1):

If you must do this (I hope you can find a different option), you should use a *hose wye*. Since you will need to covert your faucet's aerator thread to "garden hose thread" (which is what washing machine hoses use), it would be then simple to attach the hose wye which you could hook both hoses to. Open the faucet to cold or hot as needed for the washer setting and load type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simplest: Cap the hot hose, connect to the cold hose, tell the machine to wash using cold for both wash and rinse, and set the actual temperature using the sink tap controls.